# change state in modal angular ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, css

hi i am using angular ui router and angular ui to create dialog using modal , in my dialog i have two button is create and cancel , i want to when i click create ,i can go to my new state (not go back state backgroud).i am using $state.go (my new state) but error because jquery.event.dispatch .
here is my code of controller of dialog

```
.controller('inforUser',function($scope,$rootScope,$modalInstance,data,$state){
                $scope.user =$rootScope.user;// khoi tao du lieu 
                $scope.cancel = function(){
                    $modalInstance.dismiss('canceled');  
                  }; // end cancel
               $scope.save = function(){
                    $modalInstance.close($scope.user);// gui du lieu di
                   $state.go("newstate");
                  }; // end create 

            })
```

Comment: Please update question with the complete error output

Comment: Can't see any issues in your code. You probably need to setup a jsFiddle to create a demo that shows the issue. Anyway, here is a demo for a modal that changes the state to a second state after OK click. See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/yaf73z36/).